# Cocoa - How to make a search field for a tableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch, search

I have a table with several results, and now I want to make a customized search field (just a box with a text label). And I want that the table results instantly match what the user types on the search field.

Example: I tap "AN" and the table results are "Ana Fernandes", "Ana Alicia", "Ananás", etc.

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You will have a UIViewController with a normal view (ie self.view). Add a UISearhBar as a subview of self.view and put its origin at 0,0. Add a UITableView as a second subview, and set it's origin to (0, searchBar.frame.size.height). Now you have both views you want. Add yourself as a delegate to the searchbar, and implement the delegate methods so you can see what the search string is as the user enters text. You will then fuss with your tableview to just show the cells you want.